# Datatable Excel and PDF buttons not working php & Datatables

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, datatable, export

I don't know why my Datatable export buttons(export to excel ,PDF,Print,Copy) are not working

i use this form datatables.net
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

And here is my Datatable config:

what the eroor ?!
When executing code does not show me anything? The table disappears!
dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

var save_method; //for save method string
var table;


$(document).ready(function() {
 

    //datatables
    table = $('#table').DataTable({ 
 
   
  "responsive": true,
        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('personcontroller/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
   
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],
           "pageLength": 25


 dom: 'Bfrtip', // this line for export table *********
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with _my Datatable button are not working_

Comment: Export button (export table to excel or PDF)

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a comma after the `pageLength` option :

```
"pageLength": 25,
```

Comment: but the `dom` option comes follow after that, so it shouldn't work

Comment: i added the comma , but it doesn't working ? 
I cannot solve this problem :(

Comment: Could you post the error message (if there any) on the console?